# Sendmail - convert 500 fatal errors to 400 temporary errors - possible?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, proofpoint

I run a couple of email relay hosts at work.  A number of customers use **ProofPoint** as email washers, so their MX record in DNS is something like *mxa-002d7b01.gslb.pphosted.com* which washes the mail and forwards good ones onward.

Recently, proofpoint blacklisted the IP address of one of my relays.   Sendmail logs showed this.

```
Jul 31 11:15:27 smtp1 sendmail[600]: x6VZBFRHN0:
to=<destination@domainname.com>, 
relay=mxa-002d7b01.gslb.pphosted.com. [148.163.155.188],
dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

The sender address is a noreply@mydomain.com  and is configured as a DISCARD  in `/etc/mail/access`   so we ended up dumping a lot of customer emails.

**QUESTION:** is it possible to configure sendmail to treat 500 "fatal" errors as 400 "transient" errors, and requeue the emails rather than bouncing them back to the sender ?

---

Details:

Queues will grow, that's totally acceptable.  I don't have a way to regenerate those lost emails.

We're sending machine-generated emails, so they all look similar but not the same.  Messages are not spam.  Our end users pay for a larger service and these alerts are part of that service.

I don't know why proofpoint blocked that IP address, seems they don't know either.   Yes I ended up routing email via another relay, and proofpoint accepted those messages, but that's a workaround, not a solution and could go wrong again.

Comment: It is wrong, "spammer like" way to fix it.  Ham senders should keep copies and manage bounce messages.

Comment: @AnFi yes I see your point, but I'm working around what Proofpoint is doing wrong.  I don't have authority or power to re-engineer what my employer does with their emails.  In terms of scale, this was  50k emails that were permanently rejected when they should have been temporarily-rejected.

Comment: AFAIK It would require changes in sendmail's source code.

Comment: I'm not stuck to sendmail - is this functionality available in any MTA ?

Comment: Can you identify the potential troublemakers (destination domains)?  How many messages per peak hour do you send to such domains? Maybe SIMPLE custom delivery agent MAY fix the problem.

Comment: Doing this could cause other sites to mark you as a spammer, because you keep retrying rejected emails.

Comment: @Barmar yes that would be bad for all destinations, I was intending to apply it to only domains hosted by Proofpoint.  They've already broken the rules by permanently rejecting valid emails.